# is it possible to access value from a model databasetable in the application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

im trying to make a app

with users
this users can join multiple groups - every group has the same menu on the page
their group page is accessable about group/1 or group/2

so i wanted to put the the menu in the application.html.erb, with lnks depending on the group.id - but i dont know how to acces this id in the application.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often done using `content_for` in the layout. Let's say you want your menu in a certain div in `application.html.erb`:

```
# application.html.erb
<div id="menu_div>
  <ul>
  ... etc ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Replace the inner content with a `yield` statement:

```
<div id="menu_div>
  <%= yield :group_menu %>
</div>
```

Then in the view template add the `content_for` block:

```
# page
<% content_for :group_menu do %>
  <ul>
  ... etc ...
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Each page template can then define its own menu code in a  `content_for` block. This can be further generalized by using a helper method in the block and passing in instance variables.

**EDIT**

Assuming `@group` is assigned in the controller, you might do something like:

```
<% content_for :group_menu do %>
  <%= show_me_the_menu(@group) %>
<% end %>
```

and in the helper *(obviously contrived example)*:

```
def show_me_the_menu(group)
  content_tag :ul do
    group.users.collect do |user|
      concat(content_tag(:li, user.some_method))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thats awesome, thx very much, but if i need for example the group name on every site at same place (so best in application.html.erb), how needs the helper method look like? sorry for noobness

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach would be to set this in `ApplicationController` via `before_filter` and just use it as an instance variable in views.

So in controller set something like `@links =` some logic where you calculate your links based on current user.

In view you do something like:

```
<ul>
  <%- for link in @links -%>
    <li><%= link.title =>
  <%- end -%.
</ul>
```

Of course, you set your @links in ApplicationController only if you want your links to be available to all your controllers/views, which I think you do.

Rails Cells could also be used here http://cells.rubyforge.org/

Comment: the problem is, the link cant have to do with the current user, it should be connected with the users group which is visted, because it should be also possible for non registered users to visit most of the pages of a group.    i will check cells out, thx

Comment: Ok, then just set your @links based on the current group and print it out in your layout/view.

Comment: could u link me a guide showing this? im very new to rails and i tried to follow your explanation but didnt worked :/

Comment: ty, i know that sire i also watch a lot railscasts - but often it is hard to find what im searching for, especially here. probably this topic has a specific name, which i dont know ^^

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem in a different way now. i created in the group model a "menu" and this i render partial in the application.html.erb